# ng bootstrap datepicker style leak

Tags: css, angular, ng-bootstrap

I am having a problem where my ng-bootstrap `datepicker` is being styled incorrectly. Please see the following image:

[image: style issue]

It looks like there is a large margin being applied to the right side of each of the `class="ngb-dp-day"`s where the resulting size is not correct, and therefore each column of days stacks vertically on top of each other.

I have looked through the element tree and cannot seem to find any classes that may receive leaking styles from other elements.

Any of the three `ViewEncapsulation` methods (`None`, `Native`, or `Emulated`) make a difference either. Same vertical stacking.

I am rendering the datepicker inside of a `ng-bootstrap` modal body. html below:

```
<ng-template #content let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
  <div class="modal-header">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <ngb-datepicker #dp [(ngModel)]="model.dateStruct" (navigate)="date = $event.next"></ngb-datepicker>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    ...
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Any more information I can provide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kinda hard to isolate the issue with just that, I'd say that wrapping each day in a `div` element which is set to `display: block`, it's what's causing the vertical stacking.

You could try either approaches:

- Set `.ngb-dp-day`'s parent container to `display: flex;` & `flex-flow: row wrap;`

Or

- Set `div.ngb-dp-day` to `display: inline-block;` or `float: left;`